# Segmentation fault core generated

Tags: c

//Im calling three times strbrk , but i need check if is != NULL , how can do it?

```
if(strpbrk(posfind,"<") != NULL ){
    posfind =(char*)malloc(strlen(strpbrk(posfind,"<"))+strlen(posfind)*sizeof(char*));
    posfind =strcat(strpbrk(posfind,"<"),posfind);
}
```

Comment: because you provided no useful code. What the orher functions do?

Comment: I doubt this compiles, you have a syntax error (missing semi-colon at `return 0`), `chkTag` is undefined.

Comment: chkTag only check if the tag is correct <&number>and works.

Comment: If you don't provide an actual compilable example, we can only guess. Besides, if you want to know where a program segfaults, the answer is simple: **use a debugger**.

Answer (score 1):

<del>`strcat` doesn't allocate new memory for you, you need to ensure that there's enough space *before* you call it. It looks like you ran out of room in that call to `strcat`, hence *WHAM*.</del>

In the updated example, use some temporary variables to store the result of `strpbrk(posfind, "<")` and the new malloc'ed memory, like so:

```
char* temp = strpbrk(posfind, "<");
char* newstring = NULL;
if (temp != NULL) {
    // You had a typo with the size, and also don't forget to add a spot for the
    // terminating null character
    newstring = malloc((strlen(temp) + strlen(posfind) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    newstring = strcpy(newstring, temp);
    newstring = strcat(newstring, posfind);
    posfind = newstring;
}
```

Of course, you should also be checking all of the return values and freeing up any allocated memory that we no longer use.

Comment: How can malloc if i dont know how much space i need ?

Comment: Use `strlen` and calculate the amount on the fly. Store some strings in temporary variables if you have to.

Comment: posfind =(char*)malloc(strlen(strpbrk(posfind,"<"))+strlen(posfind)*sizeof(char*));

Error...

Comment: Break that down into multiple lines, you'll spot the bugs much easier.

Comment: Also, casting the return value of malloc is unnecessary and dangerous in C.

Comment: It's less dangerous to cast the return value of malloc than it is to not check the return value of malloc.

Comment: That's probably true. Checking return values is a definite must.

Comment: if(strpbrk(posfind,"<") != NULL ){
    posfind =(char*)malloc(strlen(strpbrk(posfind,"<"))+strlen(posfind)*sizeof(char*));
    posfind =strcat(strpbrk(posfind,"<"),posfind);
   } //Error too

Comment: Well, do keep in mind that you're calling `strpbrk` three times in that snippet. I'm pretty sure you should only be calling it once.

Comment: oh , i see , but how can do it then ?

Comment: Store the result in a temp variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

`strpbrk(posfind,"<")` returns a null pointer, which you are passing to `strcat`.